# Connect tables with ODBC

Tags: oracle, odbc

To connect multiple tables in Oracle with ODBC do we need to create different DSN for different tables?

Comment: Are you asking about a relational join in a single SELECT statement?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't. I can't add any more info unless you make your question more specific. Why do you think you might need more than one DSN?